# Solve $(a + b\sin(x))\sin(x) = p$ for $x$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

This problem has baffled me.
I have tried using $t = \tan(x/2)$ identities but end up with a 4 th order polynomial I cant solve.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is $x$ real? How big is $p$ relative to $a,b$? Why would you think to use the half-angle substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}p&= \sin x(a+b\sin x)\\&=a\sin x + b\sin^2 x\\&= b(\sin^2 x+\frac{a}{b}\sin x)\\&=b\bigg[\sin^2 x+\frac{a}{b}\sin x +\frac{a^2}{4b^2}\bigg]-\frac{a^2}{4b}\\&=b\bigg[\sin x+\frac{a}{2b}\bigg]^2-\frac{a^2}{4b} \end{align}$$

Via completing the square. Then, $$\sin x = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{4pb+a^2}}{2b}$$ and $$x=\sin^{-1}\left( \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{4pb+a^2}}{2b}\right)$$

This is a quadratic in $\sin x$ and can be simplified by making the substitution $\sin x =\lambda$ and the solving like a normal quadratic equation. It also helps to subtract $p$ to get $$b\sin^2 x +a\sin x -p=0$$ which is the same as $$b\lambda^2+a\lambda-p=0 $$
and is easily solved using the quadratic equation. Back substituting $\sin x$ after solving for $\lambda$ and taking the inverse sine of both sides will yield the same result.

Comment: Thanks, very impressed with the completing the square solution. Don’t know how I missed that it was a quadratic equation of sin(x)

Comment: @MarkGerrand you should really upvote and accept this answer.