# solve $(a + b \cos(x))\sin(x) = p$ for $x$

Tags: trigonometry

This is another trigonometric equation I can’t solve.  I tried using $t= \tan(\frac{x}{2})$ but got a 4th order poynomial I couldn’t solve. I can’t See how to simplify into similar terms to allow me to solve. I could do it if $p = 0$.
This is a different question than that asked previously as it contains a cos and a sin term.

Comment: are you sure you mean $b\cos x$ and not $b\sin x$ ?

Comment: Not only $p=0,$ but $a=0$ or $b=0$ also gives you very simple trig. equations. If you square the given equation and use $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x,$ then we have another $4$th degree equation in $\cos x.$

Comment: Yes afraid so. Bsin x works

Comment: I’ll try the square approach

Comment: Almost similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795793/782505) was asked an hour ago.

Comment: @SarGe same person asked it. Mark, why do you ask the same question twice?!

Comment: I can’t answer the question yet. I get a 4th degree polynomial in cos(x) which I can’t solve. Different 4th degree polynomial To the one I got with using the t=Tan (x/2) approach, but equally I can’t see how to solve.

Comment: The two different 4th degree polynomials I get are:                       t^4 + 2at^3 - (a^2-1)t^2 - 2abt + (p^2 - a^2) = 0 where t=cos(x). (From squaring both sides of the original equation).     The other is from using t = tan(x/2) and double angle identities to express in terms of “t”.                                                                                          pt^4 - 2(a-b)t^3 + 2pt^2 - 2(a+b)t + p = 0.                                       Can’t solve either.    @bumblebee

Comment: Different but similar question which require different solution technique. @gt6989b

Comment: @MarkGerrand: If you really need a general solution for the trigonometric equation, there is a general method to solve [quartic equations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation) I do not think that we can do better than this.

Comment: @MarkGerrand: If you have some specific values, then this would be a better approach. If you are trying to study solutions for different $a, b, p$ values, try drawing some graphs of $y=(a + b \cos x)\sin x$ and $y=p.$

Comment: Thanks, you help has been great. Considered solved.